# How to extract quadrupole moment and its error from $\chi^2 < \chi^2 + 1$ surface?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

I have following info: plot of $\chi^2$ minimization of 208-Rn Coulomb excitation data, Surface corresponds to regions $\chi^2 < \chi^2 + 1$ with error bars of 1$\sigma$, mean lifetime is 8 $\pm$ 0.05 ps. Using this I should be able to excract the quadrupole moment and its error from that Surface. In plot y-axis is $ME_02$ and x-axis $ME_22$ denoting transitional and diagonal matrix elements.

Any tips on what I should do ?

I took the minimum$\chi^2$ valued from the graph, it was 0.35 and drew the 1$\sigma$ error bars to that.

Comment: I don’t see how a surface or a region is defined by $\chi^2<\chi^2+1$, since this is equivalent to $0<1$, which is trie *everywhere*.

Comment: Same but I did some googling and the $\chi^2$ after the < might be the minimum of $\chi^2$ instead of just$\chi^2$ like stated (though that was the exact formation)